# How to create a valid sitemap with ExpressionEngine?

Tags: sitemap, expressionengine

I'm trying to create a sitemap using ExpressionEngine, but when I load the URL in a validator it comes up empty.

ExpressionEngine uses channels and entries to display content, so in order to create a valid sitemap I need to pull in those channel entries by using the `{exp:channel:entries}` and bringing in the content through the respective channel. The only information I've been able to find regarding creating a sitemap in EE is from a question asked a few years ago, where someone answered with a couple examples and a couple docs to look at ([link to the Q&A](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/23578/where-can-i-find-the-sitemap-xml-on-expressionengine)); however, my sitemap code looks correct and some validators say there are no errors but this is only because the URL for the sitemap ONLY shows the opening and closing urlset tags and their required info and nothing else. The file size is 431B.

** I've also tried putting in their respective "channel=__" tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="1"}
      <url>
          <loc>{site_url}</loc>
          <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
          <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
          <priority>1.00</priority>
      </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}



    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"} 
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}



    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/about/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/activities/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/blog/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/cabins/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/conservancy/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/events/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/get-involved/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/groups/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/lodges/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/lodging/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/restaurants/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/events/details/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/blog/category/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/blog/archive/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/events/details/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/golf/course/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/lodges/rooms/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/parks/restaurant/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
        <loc>{site_url}/parks/promotions/{url_title}</loc>
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}


    {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <url>
      {parents field="rel_promo_to_park"}
        <loc>{site_url}/parks/promotion-details/{url_title}/{parents:url_title}</loc>
      {/parents}
        <lastmod>{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
    {/exp:channel:entries}



</urlset>
```

I'm looking to figure out a way to create a valid sitemap with ExpressionEngine without having to purchase an addon.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `entry_id` when I needed to be using `category_id`. This simple change brought in all the urls I needed dynamically.